# How to Search Access DB and Make A DB Wide Search & Replace Operation

Tags: ms-access, search, ms-access-2010

we have an access database. We had been using `http://www.example.com` on various data sections. Now we want to search this URL and replace all occurrences.

I am not sure if **Find and Replace** utility works in this case. Because **Look in** field is set to **Current Document** but my search does not bring expected results.

The goal is only changing domain name so any URL that starts with `http://www.example.com` will be updated and URLs will start with `http://www.newexample.com`

One thing that comes to my mind is exporting 40 tables as **CSV** and doing the operation via **Notepad++** and import the resulting CSV file back to database.

Comment: Add tag for programming platform - VBA, C#, PHP, etc. If you want to do Find and Replace on data in tables, I expect code could accomplish that. Your question is too broad and does not show code attempting to solve issue, therefore is not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: if the url is in a specific field in your table you can use SQL to find the records with the URL using the like operator https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: You can also use VBA to loop each field in each table and replace values. There are examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

In the Find and Replace dialog, make sure that `Match` is set to `Any Part of Field`.